# google app script calling Named Range getRange() exception: "Area coordinates or dimensions are invalid"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, exception

The following function is part of Google sheet addon.
It reads the list of all the spreadsheet named ranges, and return the result of `map()` - an array of named ranges names and their A1Notations addresses.

```
const _SS = (() => SpreadsheetApp.getActive());

function getNRList() {
    let nrs = _SS().getNamedRanges();

    return nrs.map(nr => {
      let obj = {};
      //NR range
      obj.name = nr.getName();
      //NR add
      obj.fullA1Notation = util.getFullAdd("", "", nr.getRange());
  
      return obj;
    });
  }
```

`util.getFullAdd` is an internal function returns in this case the full a1Notation of the current named range.

This function usually runs smoothly with no problem.

but for one Named Range (or maybe spreadsheet??) the following exception occurred:

```
"Exception: Koordinaten oder Abmessungen des Bereichs sind ungültig.
    at ServerJS/clientInterface:23:55
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at getNRList (ServerJS/clientInterface:18:16)
    at excuteUserRequest (ServerJS/AddOn:456:24)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8"
```

For some reason the message is in German, probably because of the user locale the meaning by Google translate is :

> coordinates or dimensions are invalid

According the call stack (row = 23 & col = 55 number) the exception occurs when `nr.getRange()` was called.

The spreadsheet is not own by me, but to one of the users installed the addon. I only see the exception in the logger.

It actually happened in another place in the code for the same user & spreadsheet, that also loop the list of named ranges calling inside the loop to `nr.getRange()`;

Different addon task & flow, but the exact same issue.

My assumption that one on the named range in this spreadsheet is causing it.

As I want to understand the exact scenario when this might happen, I have tried to recreate such an exception to see exactly how to handle it.

I tried to defined named ranges giving "out of bound" range for example:

Sheet has 999 rows and 26 columns (up to col Z) and setting the range to AD1500. this fails as can be seen in the image.

It is possible however to do it by code `SpreadSheet.setNamedRange(name,range)`- 2nd example.

I also tried

- named range inside a sheet and then deleted the sheet
- set the named range to last row in the sheet - then delete the row.
  In both cases the it became #REF

All these named ranges passed the function without any exception.

Any idea how this can happen?

[image]

Comment: Try logging nr before the line and see what it is?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou i can not recreate it, and I do not have access to that spreadsheet. I will add production log lines, If I will not figure out what is the problem

Answer (score -1):

#### Get namedRanges names and ranges in A1 notation

```
function getNRList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let nr = ss.getNamedRanges().filter(ob => ob.getName() && ob.getRange()).reduce((a,obj) => {
    a.list.push({ "name": obj.getName(), "range": obj.getRange().getA1Notation() })
    return a;
  },{list:[],getList: function(){return this.list}}).getList()
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(nr));
}
```

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. Not asking how to return the list. There is an **exception** in one particular NamedRange (as I described above, I guess). This exception will also occur in your code `obj.getRange()`.

Comment: Try it now.  I added a filter to it.

Comment: Not only I can not really test this, as I can not recreate this scenario, I'm also not sure what you are suggesting exactly, or how do you address the **exception** comes from `ob.getRange()`. Maybe I was not clear, sorry for that. I am not asking for code solution, I was asking why did this exception occur.

Comment: It just seems to me that it was an invalid range.  Maybe range went off of sheet. I can't reproduce the error since I don't have your named ranges or spreadsheet

Comment: I think that as well, only I wasn't able to recreate it as I showed above. In any case, **the exception will still happen with your solution**. I simply wrapped the `nr.getRange()` with `try-catch` and handled the "non valid" nr.